# Xamarin.Forms Toolbar Menu Animation issue

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I´m developing a Xamarin Forms application. I added two Toolbar items to a content page by setting the Order property to 'Secondary' so it appears on a menu just on the right. If I select any toolbar item it is moving to the top-left part of the screen before it dissapears.I've implemented this toolbar menu before also but never face this kind of issue and don't know why is it behaving like this.Is there any way to remove this animation,can anyone please help me with this.

Here is my code for toolbar items

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Text="Action1" Order="Secondary" Priority="0" Command="{Binding Action1Command}"/>
    <ToolbarItem Text="Action2" Order="Secondary" Priority="1" Command="{Binding Action2Command}"/>
    <ToolbarItem Text="Action3" Order="Secondary" Priority="2" Command="{Binding Action3Command}"/>
    <ToolbarItem Text="Action4" Order="Secondary" Priority="3" Command="{Binding Action3Command}"/>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Add toolbar item in XAML page for both pages.

Comment: @NicoRiff,I've seen your question regarding the same issue and you solved it by setting the `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` but it doesn't work in my case,Is there any work around to achieve this?

Comment: When clicking `ToolbarItem`,having a try to cancle the animation when pushing to next page.`Navigation.PushAsync(new NextPage(), false);`

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried adding toolbar items on XAML?
for example

```
 <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Name="Search" Clicked="search_clicked" Icon="search.png" Priority="0"  />
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

Comment: ,Thank you for the response. I've added the toolbar items from XAML page only not from code behind

Comment: Did you set priority?

Comment: ,Sure,I've modified my question(with code added) can you please have a look at the code.Thank you

Comment: Hi i checked your code and it works fine. What are you doing after the toolbar item click?

Comment: The toolbar item click navigate to other page with some workaround